# Вывести кол-во гласных в введенном предложении

Tags: python

Пользователь вводит предложение на одной строке. Определите и выведите количество гласных в введённом предложении.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Приложите вашу попытку решения и у нас всё получится.

Comment: `vowels_qty = sum(map(lambda x: x.lower() in 'аеиоыёуэюя', input("Введите строку: ")))`

Answer (score 2):

Считаем количество гласных и выводим это количество

```py
line = input("Введите строку> ")

vowels = ['а', 'я', 'у', 'ю', 'о', 'е', 'ё', 'э', 'и', 'ы']

counter = 0

for letter in line:
    if letter in vowels:
        counter+=1
print(counter)
```